# Basics about d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, d3.js

I have a few questions about the following d3.js code. I referred to their Github and some tutorials, but I am too much of a bozo to understand their language.

Please, if there is someone who understands the very basics of d3js, give me a simple elaboration on my questions below.

**Please don't suggest me a link!!!**

The code basically creates this following table:

[image: This is the output]

```
var dataset = [],
tmpDataset = [],
i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0, tmpDataset = []; j < 3; j++) {
        tmpDataset.push("Row:"+i+",Col:"+j);
    }
    dataset.push(tmpDataset);
}

d3.select("#viz")
    .append("table")
    .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
    .style("border", "2px black solid")

    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("tr")

    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d){return d;})
    .enter().append("td")
    .style("border", "1px black solid")
    .style("padding", "10px")
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "aliceblue")}) 
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")}) 
    .text(function(d){return d;})
    .style("font-size", "12px");
```

#### Questions:

1. Why are we doing `selectall("tr")` when there is no tr in our HTML? What'ss the point in selecting 'tr' which is not even there.
2. What is `data(dataset)` doing for tr?
3. What is `data(function(d){return d;})` for td? And what is the difference between 2 and 3?

Comment: The answers to your first 3 questions are for example in [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html). For question 4, I suggest having a look at [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). Your last question is also answered by the first tutorial.

Comment: yaa,I saw that thing earlier,But please i understand things in more practical way,I went through the same example that the link has but i was not able to understand it completely.I would be great if you could explain me in simple language.just the basic mechanism,Plz no more links.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yey links!

Comment: @jayeshjain just tweak the code, see what happens if you remove a line or change some parameters, and you'll understand. Btw most of the syntax is close to most popular DOM libraries around, not any rocket science.

Comment: @jayeshjain: sorry, but we're not here to translate English into simpler English. We're here answer programming questions. Stack Overflow is an English language website. It'd be great if we could get more speakers of different languages on too, but we're not a translation service.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite:I totally understand,and its not like I havent done any research,but this is the first time around d3js.Thats why I am asking it.I myself have flagged some questions that were kind off similar to my question.But i am terribly confused about whats actually happening.
a line or two would do.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:a line or two would do!!!I just want the basic concept of it.No fancy code.just a simple line or two would do.

Comment: I can see you’ve done research; that’s good. I’m sure it is your first time with d3.js. That doesn’t change the fact that we’re not here to translate the d3.js documentation, or to give you a general explanation of d3.js. Your question is made up of 5 individual questions — it might help to ask each one individually, with a descriptive title.

Comment: That's what's in the tutorial. I can't really make it any simpler than that. There are certain concepts that need to be explained and omitting them will not help you understand.

Comment: @jayeshjain: we’re not complaining that you’re asking us to write too many lines. Please listen to what we’re saying — that’ll get you further than just repeating a request.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:ok,I do my homework onceAgain!!!thanks everybody!!!

Comment: @LarsKotthoff:thanks for the link.That was gr8.But when should I use selectall and select...how do i know that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 . Why are we doing `selectall("tr")` when there is no tr in our HTML? What'ss the point in selecting 'tr' which is not even there.

`selectall` is a misnomer in d3, a very poorly named function. It does not so much select as put you in a process space related to what would be there. For example if there are `tr`s there it will allow you to talk to them, if not it will allow you to talk to the potential `tr`s that will be there. Its useful to have both as one function, but its definitely not a select.

> 2 . After we have apended `"tr"`, is there no need for a closing '`</tr>'`? Why is `</tr>` not appended?

The closing `</tr>` tag should be appending in that command. The reality is you are appending a dom element with the tag type of `tr`, not a string `<tr>`, so it will be complete out of the box.

> 3 . What is `data(dataset)` doing for tr?

`data` "attaches" data to the element. If you look in the dom it actually adds it to a `__data__` attribute of the element's in memory representation. The purpose here is to allow you to operate on that data or the element in tandem. For instance `function(d){ return d;}` is getting `d` from the attached data.

> 4 . What is `data(function(d){return d;})` for td? And what is the difference between 3 and 4?

`d` is the attached data. Had you attached an array of objects you could be doing things like `.text(function(d){ return d.name }).attr('height', function(d){ return d.value });`

> 5 . What does this code do? `.data([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32], function(d) { return d; });`

Its attaching the data to the elements, then looping through them and operating on that data using the `d` variable.

Comment: :when should I use selectall and select...how do i know that??

Comment: How do you know it? Well you could ask people on SO ;) Truth is d3 is brilliant, but its more of a big pile of brilliance than anything well organized. The guy who wrote it is more of an academic than a developer from what I can tell.

Comment: The difference between `selectall` and `select` is similar to `queryselectorall` and `queryselector`. Basically do you want to select one of a thing, or all of the things.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the `.selectAll("tr")` as an iteration on all existing "tr" tags. What is happening is that we attach new data to these `tr` tags. Thus, if some `tr` tags already existed, their content would be replaced with the content generated by the new data. If no tags exists, then they will be created.

Now what is happening with `.data(array)`? This just means that we will iterate on all elements of `array` and generate one element per array.

I suggest you should have a closer look at DOM and d3.js examples. Playing with examples by removing lines as suggested by moonwave99 will most certainly help you learn faster.